# Is using htmlspecialchars() and using placeholders in SQL enough to stop attacks on my website?

Tags: php, sql, forms, security

I have finally finished my login and register form WITH e-mail verification and I am *SO* happy! I am just not sure if my form is secure enough. I've used htmlspecialcharacters() on all user inputs and used placeholders in SQL queries. Is this enough to stop attacks on my form? Please help, as all answers are appreciated. Thanks! This is the code for my register form: http://pastebin.com/FWsDqeKs

```
<?php
include_once 'compat.php';
$user = 0;
$pass = 0;
$mail = 0;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['mail']) && !empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {

    function an($subject) {
        if(ctype_alnum($subject)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if(an($_POST['user']) && strlen($_POST['user']) <= 20) {
        $user = htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']);
    }
    else {
        echo 'username is invalid (a-z A-Z 0-9 and less than 20 characters, please)<br>';
    }
    if(filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && strlen($_POST['mail']) <= 255) {
        $mail = htmlspecialchars($_POST['mail')];
    }
    else {
        echo 'email is invalid<br>';
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['pass']) <= 255) {
        $pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']);
    }
    else {
        echo 'password must be less than 255 characters<br>';
    }
    if($pass && $user && $mail) {
        $hash = md5(rand(0, 1000));
        require_once('db.php');
        $sth = $db->prepare("
                                INSERT INTO user_info (username, password, email, hash)
                                VALUES (:username, :password, :mail, :hash)
                ");
        $sth->bindValue(":username", $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(":password", password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(":mail", $mail, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(":hash", $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $success = $sth->execute();
        echo 'You have been successfully signed up :)! To activate your account, click the link in your e-mail account (check your spam box if you don\'t get the e-mail!)<br>
                The last step to activating your account is clicking this link!:<br>
                http://localhost/verify.php?mail=' . $mail . '&hash=' . $hash . '<br>
                ';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: if you would provide us some example code, so we can take a look at it. would be very useful

Comment: What do you mean by "placeholders"? Do you mean parameterized prepared statements?

Comment: How you perform SQL-queries is more important in this case. I hope you don't use `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: Using `htmlspecialchars` to insert data into a database is a sure sign you don't really know what you're doing... Prepared statements are all you need. `htmlspecialchars` is for outputting to the browser.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: You are making assumptions. It might turn out that the OP actually does that, but it doesn't follow from the question.

Comment: Hi, rsz! I've updated the post, providing a pastebin link to the register form on my website. Thank you! :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: functions like htmlspecialchars could potentially be useful in preventing 2nd order injection attacks. There are probably better ways, though.

Comment: Hey @user3344396 - I edited your question to include your PHP code into the question. Something I noticed: you've got a typo on line 18; you mixed up the ending bracket and parenthesis.

Comment: Hi @ChrisForrence! Sorry that I haven't included a code block, I haven't used this site much since I signed up. Thanks for noticing the typo and fixing my post!

Comment: Not so fast ;-) You're not quite done yet. Don't use MD5 for password storage, it's broken, *busted* you know... **unsafe to use**. Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Hio @Fred -ii! That MD5 is not for storing the password, but in fact, storing a hash for the e-mail verification link. As you can see in the line including "password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)", I'm using password_hash to store passwords.

Comment: @user3344396 Silly me, my mistake. Good stuff then ;-) Well, you should be good to go then! The other comments are also useful.

Comment: @siride, mucking about with the data before you store it might be a good idea as long as there is no possibility that it will be displayed but on a web page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be more appropriate on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/